# Elasticsearch remove special characters (from non ascii based language)

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

For english, I could use something like

```
       "specialCharactersFilter": {
         "pattern": "[^A-Za-z0-9]",
         "type": "pattern_replace",
         "replacement": ""
       }
     }
```

to remove non-text characters.

However, for non-ascii language such as asian, the above filter removes all valid non-special characters.

How to remove special characters from asian language?

Comment: If it is Java regex engine in place here, you may  use `"pattern": "[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]"`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by java regex engine , but it seems to work.. (i guess because Elasticsearch is java based and I guess you mean that.)

Comment: Elasticsearch uses different regex engines, sometimes Lucene, sometimes, `java.util.regex`.

Comment: it took some time (7 min to pick an answer ) after posting question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the regex flavor used in `pattern_replace` filter is [`java.util.regex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true).

To remove any characters other than any Unicode letter and decimal digit, you may use

```
 "specialCharactersFilter": {
     "pattern": "[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]",
     "type": "pattern_replace",
     "replacement": ""
   }
```

To make sure you only keep ASCII digits and remove all Hindi, Tamil etc. digits, you may use a variation like

```
"pattern": "[^\\p{L}0-9]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0HKRGm/1).